# Creating multidimentional arrays that loop through database info

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, while-loop, simple-machines-forum

I feel really stupid asking this and I've searched around before and had a bit of help but not really. I really want to understand how to do this.

Basically I want the output to be [something like this](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=DkhvauXR)

The problem I am having is I am not sure how to make sure the type is not a child type and to loop through infinitely if needed for subtypes... or at least 3, possibly 4 times.

Here's [an SQL dump](http://pastebin.com/dBPWNF3A).
Here's [my not working code](http://pastebin.com/beBAMhD6).
Here's [what it's outputting](http://pastebin.com/sUKqYREq).
Here's [what I want it to output](http://pastebin.com/ivjgnNP5) (note the type IDs in the subtypes is being used instead of starting from 1 again, note also that if sonnet had a sub type it would do the same thing for sonnet).

If anyone could help me at all that would be fantastic. I really want to learn and understand how to do this correctly but I'm very lost!

Sorry for all the links I keep getting "your post has improperly formatted code" even using pre tags on that first link....it's been rough posting this :(.

Comment: Please post the code & result *in the question*. Be sure to use the 'Code Sample' button (or Ctrl+K) in toolbar at the top of the editor to properly format the code. You should also try keep the samples as brief as possible while still conveying the core idea.

Comment: Try to re-create your problem in a database much smaller and a code much simpler so we can help you with the logic of it. That way you can learn what you're doing wrong and replicate the solution into your real problem.

Comment: That's a TEENY database, it has like 30 rows. And I TRIED for over an HOUR to post this message but kept getting errors, even if it was just the URLs I got errors. This is the best I can do, sorry if it's not good enough but I tried my best :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work with this :)

```js
function getCategoriesTypes($workIndexOptions)
{
 global $smcFunc, $scripturl, $user_info, $modSettings, $txt;
 global $settings, $options, $context, $sourcedir;

  $result_work_cats_and_types = $smcFunc['db_query']('workindex_fetch_cats_and_types' , '
  SELECT
   c.id_cat,
   c.cat_order,
   c.cat_name,
   c.cat_desc,
   t.id_type,
   t.id_cat AS parent_cat,
   t.id_parent,
   t.child_level,
   t.type_order,
   t.type_name,
   t.type_desc,
   t.num_works,
   t.num_comments,
   t.unapproved_comments
  FROM
   {db_prefix}works_categories AS c,
   {db_prefix}works_types AS t
  WHERE
   c.id_cat = t.id_cat
  ORDER BY
   c.cat_order, t.id_parent
 ');

 // Start with an empty array.
 $work_categories = array();
 
 while ($row = $smcFunc['db_fetch_assoc']($result_work_cats_and_types))
 {
  if (!isset($work_categories[$row['id_cat']]))
  {
   $work_categories[$row['id_cat']] = array(
    'id' => $row['id_cat'],
    'order' => $row['cat_order'],
    'name' => $row['cat_name'],
    'description' => $row['cat_desc'],
    'href' => $scripturl . '#c' . $row['id_cat'],
    'types' => array() ,
   );
  }

  
  if (($work_categories[$row['child_level']]) == 0)
  {
  $work_categories[$row['id_cat']]['types'][$row['id_type']] = array(
   'id' => $row['id_type'],
   'order' => $row['type_order'],
   'parent_cat' => $row['parent_cat'],
   'parent' => $row['id_parent'],
   'child_level' => $row['child_level'],
   'name' => $row['type_name'],
   'description' => $row['type_desc'],
   'works' => $row['num_works'],
   'comments' => $row['num_comments'],
   'href' => $scripturl . '?type=' . $row['id_type'] . '.0',
   'link' => '<a href="' . $scripturl . '?type=' . $row['id_type'] . '.0">' . $row['type_name'] . '</a>',
   'types' => array() ,
  );
  }
 
  if (($work_categories[$row['child_level']]) > 0)
  {
  $work_categories[$row['id_cat']]['types'][$row['id_parent']]['types'][$row['id_type']] = array(
   'id' => $row['id_type'],
   'order' => $row['type_order'],
   'parent_cat' => $row['parent_cat'],
   'parent' => $row['id_parent'],
   'child_level' => $row['child_level'],
   'name' => $row['type_name'],
   'description' => $row['type_desc'],
   'works' => $row['num_works'],
   'comments' => $row['num_comments'],
   'href' => $scripturl . '?type=' . $row['id_type'] . '.0',
   'link' => '<a href="' . $scripturl . '?type=' . $row['id_type'] . '.0">' . $row['type_name'] . '</a>',
  );
  }
 }
 $smcFunc['db_free_result']($result_work_cats_and_types);
 
 // Let's return something....
 return $work_categories;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

With such a big code sample, it's hard to do any kind of testing, but this might get you a bit closer to your goal:

```
<?php
function getCategoriesTypes($workIndexOptions)
    {
        global $smcFunc, $scripturl, $user_info, $modSettings, $txt;
        global $settings, $options, $context, $sourcedir;

        $result_work_cats_and_types = $smcFunc['db_query']('workindex_fetch_cats_and_types' , '
                SELECT
                        c.id_cat,
                        c.cat_order,
                        c.cat_name,
                        c.cat_desc,
                        t.id_type,
                        t.id_cat AS parent_cat,
                        t.id_parent,
                        t.child_level,
                        t.type_order,
                        t.type_name,
                        t.type_desc,
                        t.num_works,
                        t.num_comments,
                        t.unapproved_comments
                FROM
                        {db_prefix}works_categories AS c,
                        {db_prefix}works_types AS t
                WHERE
                        c.id_cat = t.id_cat

        ');

        // Start with an empty array.
        $work_categories = array();

        while ($row = $smcFunc['db_fetch_assoc']($result_work_cats_and_types)) {
                if (!isset($work_categories[$row['id_cat']])) {
                        $work_categories[$row['id_cat']] = array(
                                'id' => $row['id_cat'],
                                'order' => $row['cat_order'],
                                'name' => $row['cat_name'],
                                'description' => $row['cat_desc'],
                                'href' => $scripturl . '#c' . $row['id_cat'],
                                'types' => array()
                            );
                    }

                $idCat      =   $row['id_cat'];
                $idType     =   $row['id_type'];
                $idOrder    =   $row['order'];
                // You shouldn't generate these two arrays at the same time on every loop
                // Try doing if for the first, else for the rest.
                // Identify a unique element like order and child.
                // Assuming `child_level` will always be 0 for parent and signify new
                // array when `order` changes (I am not sure, it's hard to tell how you
                // are signifying organizing triggers. The order seems common to child and parent arrays...??)
                if($row['child_level'] == 0 && !isset($work_categories[$idCat]['types'][$idOrder])) {
                        // I put $row['order'] here as the identifying array key because I don't 
                        // see any other difference from your other keys that indicate new array
                        $work_categories[$idCat]['types'][$idOrder] = array(
                                'id' => $row['id_type'],
                                'order' => $row['type_order'],
                                'parent_cat' => $row['parent_cat'],
                                'child_level' => $row['child_level'],
                                'name' => $row['type_name'],
                                'description' => $row['type_desc'],
                                'works' => $row['num_works'],
                                'comments' => $row['num_comments'],
                                'href' => $scripturl . '?type=' . $row['id_type'] . '.0',
                                'link' => '<a href="' . $scripturl . '?type=' . $row['id_type'] . '.0">' . $row['type_name'] . '</a>',
                                'types' => array());
                    }
                else {
                        // Use the `order` key here (I am assuming)
                        $work_categories[$idCat]['types'][$idOrder]['types'][$idType] = array(
                            'id' => $row['id_type'],
                            'order' => $row['type_order'],
                            'parent_cat' => $row['parent_cat'],
                            'child_level' => $row['child_level'],
                            'name' => $row['type_name'],
                            'description' => $row['type_desc'],
                            'works' => $row['num_works'],
                            'comments' => $row['num_comments'],
                            'href' => $scripturl . '?type=' . $row['id_type'] . '.0',
                            'link' => '<a href="' . $scripturl . '?type=' . $row['id_type'] . '.0">' . $row['type_name'] . '</a>'); 
                    }
            }
    } ?>
```

Comment: Note, I made a couple revisions...See if this works for you. The first post didn't have a parent id, so it probably won't work...not to say this version will work, but in my mind it should work! :D

Comment: Thanks so much for giving this a go! I had to change the idOrder stuff to idType to get it to work, and it works....except that the subtypes (last but of code) is just adding them to the end of the list....if that makes sense?

It goes poetry, screenplay, then the rest, then puts sonnet and the others last, instead of under poetry. Have a look here: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=VQMjnD7n